# dynamic if boolean with module lookup

Tags: python, boolean-expression

I'm relatively new to python, and I'm trying to figure out an issue, where I'm trying to write a generalised function.

In this scenario, I have a `settings_file.py` file alongside my `app.py` program. The `settings_file.py` is optional.

Content of `settings_file.py`:

```
myvariable = "foo"
```

Earlier in my program I (optionally) import the settings file:

```
try:
    import settings_file
except ImportError:
    pass
```

native version:

```
if settings_file.myvariable:
  print "myvariable found from settings_file!"
  return settings_file.myvariable
```

What I'm trying to do:

```
element_name = "myvariable"

if settings_file.eval(element_name):
  print "{} found from settings_file!".format(element_name)
  return settings_file.element_name
```

I think what I'm struggling with, is the if statement line, more spefically, the `settings_file.eval(element_name)` part.

I'm quite new to this, and my understanding is python should resolve the `element_name` back to a string for me. Maybe I have not typeset correctly.

I cant get it to resolve the variable name.

Edit: Perhaps I've not been clear, or misleading. I'm trying to return the value in the settings file back from a generalised function that I'm writing this element within. My desired outcome is that "foo" will be returned, which is the value of variable "myvariable" in `settings_file.py`.

Edit2: I think I worked out something based on response from @9769953

```
if getattr(settings_file, element_name, None):
  print "{} found from settings_file!".format(element_name)
  return getattr(settings_file, element_name, None)
```

Comment: @BlackBear I appreciate you taking the time to respond. thanks.

Comment: Why the `if` statement with `getattr()`? What happens after the `if` statement if it evaluates to `None`? Because now you're calling `getattr()` twice, which doesn't really make sense.

Comment: There are other parts to the function that I did not include in this question.
The point is to check and return the value, *if it is present* and continue the function if it is not present.
It might not be a strictly tidy method, but it seems to work well within the context of where it is used. It's a great solution, thanks.

Comment: "if it is present": perhaps then it's clearer to use `foo = getattr(settings_file, element_name, None)\nif foo:\nreturn foo`. That works, unless element_name actually exists, but evaluates to False, 0, None, empty string etc. Otherwise, consider `if settings_file and hasattr(settings_file, element_name):`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're evaluating variable names, or otherwise want flexible variable names, 9 out of 10 times, you should use `dict`s.

Here, there is (even) more going on: you should first check that `settings_file` actually exist, before trying to get an attribute. Then, you could use `getattr(settings_file, element_name)`:

```
try:
    import settings_file
except ImportError:
    settings_file = None

...

element_name = "myvariable"
return getattr(settings_file, element_name, None)
```

which returns `None` in case `"myvariable"` was not found, or the import failed. It doesn't explicitly test for `settings_file` not to be `None`, since `getattr()` will then just return `None` whatever the value of `element_name`.

Comment: Maybe I've been misleading. I'm trying to return the value "foo" in the settings_file back. My desired outcome is that "foo" will be returned, which is the value of variable "myvariable" in `settings_file.py`
Does this solution do that?

Comment: Yes, this works, I put an edit on the question to reflect what worked in the end. Thanks.